# How to make it as a diamond

Tags: tikz-arrows

how to made this as a diamond please like " C under A"

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\linespread{1.5} 
\textwidth=16truecm \textheight=23truecm  \voffset=-1truecm
\hoffset=-1 truecm \thispagestyle{empty}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc, decorations.markings, positioning, quotes}
\usepackage{cite,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 5cm and 5cm,
     C/.style = {circle, draw=black, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, minimum size=5cm,
                 },
   dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2mm,
                 node contents={}},
     L/.style = {decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.7 with {\arrow{>}}line width=60mm},
                 postaction={decorate}},
every edge quotes/.append style = {anchor=south , sloped, font=\footnotesize},
every edge/.append style = {L} 
                 ]
% main nodes
\node (A) [dot];
\node (B) [dot, below right=of A];%  {2};
\node (C) [dot, below = of A ];%        {3};
\node (D) [dot,below left =of A];%  {5};

% dots
\draw[L]    ($(A)+(0, 5mm)$) circle (4mm) node {1};
\draw[L]    ($(B)+( 5mm,0)$) circle (4mm) node {2};
\draw[L]    ($(C)+( 5mm,0)$) circle (4mm) node {3};
\draw[L]    ($(D)+(-5mm,0)$) circle (4mm) node {4};


    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: `\node (C) [dot, below =10cm of A ];`?

Comment: @CarLaTeX no it doesn't work

Comment: Could you add an image of the desired result? Also a photo of a hand-written drawing is enough, thank you!

Comment: @CarLaTeX it must be below =of A, below right=of B, below left=of D

Comment: @CarLaTeX i don't have a picture of the desired result

Comment: yes it doesn't work @CarLaTeX

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

This code (the only lines changed have `%CHANGED` as a comment):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\linespread{1.5} 
\textwidth=16truecm \textheight=23truecm  \voffset=-1truecm
\hoffset=-1 truecm \thispagestyle{empty}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc, decorations.markings, positioning, quotes}
\usepackage{cite,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 5cm and 5cm,
    C/.style = {circle, draw=black, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, minimum size=5cm,
    },
    dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2mm,
        node contents={}},
    L/.style = {decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.7 with {\arrow{>}}line width=60mm},
        postaction={decorate}},
    every edge quotes/.append style = {anchor=south , sloped, font=\footnotesize},
    every edge/.append style = {L} 
    ]
    % main nodes
    \node (A) [dot];
    \node (B) [dot, below right=of A];%  {2};
    \node (C) [dot, below =10cm of A ];%        {3};%CHANGED
    \node (D) [dot,below left =of A];%  {5};

    % dots
    \draw[L]    ($(A)+(0, 5mm)$) circle (4mm) node {1};
    \draw[L]    ($(B)+( 5mm,0)$) circle (4mm) node {2};
    \draw[L]    ($(C)+(0,-5mm)$) circle (4mm) node {3};%CHANGED
    \draw[L]    ($(D)+(-5mm,0)$) circle (4mm) node {4};


    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Give me this output:

[image]

Please let me know what is missing.

Comment: i don't understand now it works ! thank you

Answer (score 2):

you were very close ...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, decorations.markings, positioning, quotes}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 5cm and 5cm,
     C/.style = {circle, draw=black, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, minimum size=5cm,
                 },
   dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2mm,
                 node contents={}},
     L/.style = {decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.7 with {\arrow{>}}line width=60mm},
                 postaction={decorate}},
every edge quotes/.append style = {anchor=south , sloped, font=\footnotesize},
every edge/.append style = {L}
                 ]
% main nodes
\node (A) [dot];
\node (B) [dot, below right=of A];
\node (C) [dot, below left =of B ];% this node you like to have below of A 
                                   % but it is also below left from node B.      
\node (D) [dot, below left =of A];
% dots
\draw[L]    ($(A)+(0, 5mm)$) circle (4mm) node {1};
\draw[L]    ($(B)+( 5mm,0)$) circle (4mm) node {2};
\draw[L]    ($(C)+(0,-5mm))$) circle (4mm) node {3};
\draw[L]    ($(D)+(-5mm,0)$) circle (4mm) node {4};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]